# How to Change Elements in a Circular Pattern from an Image Matrix in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv, multidimensional-array, mask

Although this is related to OpenCV, it's more of an array manipulation technique question than OpenCV.

I currently have a video stream set up using OpenCV and a camera in Python.
I'm trying to mask a circular area in the center by flipping all elements inside a matrix into zeros in a circular pattern.

So far, I was mildly successful at covering up the center area by slicing the matrix and replacing the elements using the function below

```
def get_inside_square(raw_radius, matrix, center):
     #raw_radius is the radius of the circular area I want to mask
     #matrix is the image feed coming in from the camera
     #center is a 1D array using pixel counts as coordinates i.e [320,240] in a 480p video stream
     #subtract 1/3.3 of the radius on each side to get rough inscribed square
     offset = 5
     center_x = center[0]
     center_y = center[1]
     div = 3.3
     horizontal=[left,right] = [center_x-(raw_radius/div),center_x+(raw_radius/div)]
     vertical=[bottom,top] = [center_y-(raw_radius/div),center_y+(raw_radius/div)]
     matrix[int(bottom-offset):int(top+offset), int(left-offset):int(right+offset)]=0
     filtered = matrix
     return filtered
```

[Screen Capture of my current image using the above function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WnlSk.png)

What would be the best way to slice the 2-D array to select a circular shape so that I don't see the square edges on the blobs and still cover up the entire area?

Comment: Why not just draw a filled circle? See cv2.circle() at https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.1/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#gaf10604b069374903dbd0f0488cb43670

Comment: fmw42 Thank you!!! I didn't realize it would be this simple!

Comment: if you can precompute the shape you can create a mask and use .setTo function on the image with that mask. Migjt be a bit faster and allows arbitrary shapes.